# Mesh changes on multiple objects while keeping other properties

Tags: mesh, materials, modifiers, transforms, workflow

Let's say I'm modeling a chair. The object is placed in different locations on my scenes, with different modifiers, transform data, and materials. Now I want to make changes to the chair's mesh using the sculpting tools. Is there a way to only apply the mesh changes to all chairs while keeping all the individual properties of each chair, such as materials, transforms, etc. Thanks!

Comment: if you've used instances of the same mesh, the sculpt will change the mesh and each object should keep its transforms, modifiers and materials

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic links + library overrides work best for me when using the same object multiple times within a scene. In this way, I can assign different materials, modifiers, constraints, and transforms to each individual copy of the object (which I think is impossible with instances). When I want to manipulate the mesh itself, I can do this and update all objects in the scene simultaneously.

This is how I built up the scene:

**Object**
In file A I created the object (e.g., chair), which I want to use with different materials, modifiers, and transforms on different locations in a scene.

**Scene**
I created file B to set up the scene (e.g., bar) and imported the object as a dynamic link.
(File/linked/...)

In the outliner, I can define that new materials, modifiers, etc., can be assigned to the object.
(Right-click/ID Data/Make Library Override)

The object can now be duplicated and manipulated with individual materials, modifiers, constraints, and transforms for each individual copy.